mi input no setea el campo como corresponde
Tengo un problema con un sistema que he estado intentado modificar.
Es de una tienda. lo primero que sucede es que es un material que se vender por mtrs2 o por piés cuadrados.
para calcular la cantidad de material que la gente necesita comprar he creado un modal donde la persona coloca el ancho y el alto para calcular el área y que posteriormente se coloque en el input de la cantidad lo que corresponde para luego pasar eso con un botón de agregar al carrito

Al Presionar el botón CALCULATE ROLLS se abre el siguiente modal

Hasta ahora la cantidad está en 1
pero al colocar el ancho y el alto puedo obtener el valor y puedo por JS pasarlo al input de la cantidad a través del ID

hasta acá todo parece estar bien, pero en realidad ese input sigue con un valor de 1. al enviar al carrito se carga 1 solo... para que este input me tome el valor que posee en este momento; debo situarme al final del input y pisar la barra espaciadora pero esto es algo que hago manualmente. no está funcionando de manera automática. intenté emular que despues de hacer un focus se setee la pulsación de la barra espaciadora y según la consola si se setea pero en el input no se actualiza el valor. queda todo igual, la unica forma en que trabaja es parandome en el input al final y presionar barra espaciadora.
Si alguno tiene una idea.
Por ejemplo acá se enviar el valor correspondiente a 91. pero la flecha de + está habilitada mientras la de - está inhabilitada, si piso el más sale un numero 2 y se habilita el signo -

en cambio si me paro en el input y piso barra espaciadora, entonces se habilita el signo - y por supuesto si subo o bajo por las flechas + ó - lo hará desde dicho número.

todo lo estoy haciendo por JS y este es mi código
<!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="calculatorModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="calculatorModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="panel-body" id="calculatorModalLongTitle">Wallpaper Calculator
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div class="my-profile">
                    <h5 class="roll-calculator-modal-subtitle">Your Room Dimensions</h5>
                    <p class="roll-calculator-modal-description">Add the widths of all walls and measure the highest
                        point of the walls.</p>
                    <div>
                        <br>
                        Feet
                        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck" />
                        Meters
                        <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck" />
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        <div id="ifYes" style="display:none" class="form-group">
                            <label>Width (feet) <input id="box1" type="number" min="0"></label>
                            <label>Height (feet) <input id="box2" type="number" min="0" oninput="calculate();"></label>

                            <h5 id="result"></h5>

                        </div>
                        <div id="ifNo" style="display:none" class="form-group">
                            <label>Width (m) <input id="box3" type="number" min="0" oninput="calculate1();"></label>
                            <label>Height (m) <input id="box4" type="number" min="0" oninput="calculate1();"></label>
                            <label for="result1"><input id="result1" type="text" readonly class="custom" size="32"/>Mt<sup>2</sup> needed</label>
                            <div class="rolls-number">0 units needed</div>
                            <div class="price">$0</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    
                </div>

                <form @input="errors.clear($event.target.name)" @submit.prevent="addToCart">
                    <div class="details-info-middle-actions"style="padding-left:30px">
                        <div class="number-picker-lg">
                            <label for="qty1">{{ trans('storefront::product.quantity') }}</label>
                            <div class="input-group-quantity">
                                <input type="text" :value="cartItemForm.qty" min="1"
                                    :max="maxQuantity" id="qty1"
                                    class="form-control input-number input-quantity" :disabled="isAddToCartDisabled"
                                    @focus="$event.target.select()"
                                    @input="updateQuantity($event, Number($event.target.value))"
                                    @keydown.up="updateQuantity($event, cartItemForm.qty + 1)"
                                    @keydown.down="updateQuantity($event, cartItemForm.qty - 1)">

                                <span class="btn-wrapper">
                                    <button type="button" aria-label="quantity" class="btn btn-number btn-plus"
                                        :disabled="isQtyIncreaseDisabled"
                                        @click="updateQuantity($event, cartItemForm.qty + 1)">
                                        +
                                    </button>

                                    <button type="button" aria-label="quantity" class="btn btn-number btn-minus"
                                        :disabled="isQtyDecreaseDisabled"
                                        @click="updateQuantity($event, cartItemForm.qty - 1)">
                                        -
                                    </button>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-add-to-cart"
                            :class="{ 'btn-loading': addingToCart }" :disabled="isAddToCartDisabled"
                            v-text="isActiveItem ? $trans('storefront::product.add_to_cart') : $trans('storefront::product.unavailable')">
                            {{ trans($item->is_active ? 'storefront::product.add_to_cart' : 'storefront::product.unavailable') }}
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <br>

                </form>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <p>How do I measure my wall?</p>
                    {{-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button> --}}
                    {{-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button> --}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Dentro del script intenté colocar un botón que hiciera el focus a ese campo y se posicionara al final para que luego se seteara la key correspondiente a la barra espaciadora y ene fecto se va al final pero no cumple la funcion que requiero que cumpla que es que se registre ese valor de ese input calculad
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';

    }
    function calculate() {
        var myBox1 = document.getElementById('box1').value;
        var myBox2 = document.getElementById('box2').value;
        var result = document.getElementById('result');
        var qty = document.getElementById('qty1');
        var myResult = myBox1 * myBox2;


        document.getElementById('result').textContent = (Math.ceil(myResult) + ' sq ft needed');

        qty.value =(Math.ceil(myResult));
        var btn = document.getElementById('btn');

        document.addEventListener('keydown', function(ev){
  console.log(ev.which);
});



btn.addEventListener('click', function handleClick() {
  // ️ get length right before clicking button
  var end = qty.value.length;

  qty.setSelectionRange(end, end);
  qty.focus();
});
    }
    function calculate1() {
        var myBox3 = document.getElementById('box3').value;
        var myBox4 = document.getElementById('box4').value;
        var result1 = document.getElementById('result1');
        var myResult = myBox3 * myBox4;
        document.getElementById('result1').textContent = myResult;

    }
    function yesnoCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'none';
        } else if (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }

    function yesnoCheck1() {
        if (document.getElementById('redhat').checked) {
            document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'none';
        }
        if (document.getElementById('aix').checked) {
            document.getElementById('aix1').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('redhat1').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }


</script>



A mi parecer no se entiende muy bien tu problema. Estaría bien tener un enlace a una reproducción simple del proyecto para ver el problema.
